# video.js and multiple language tracks - default flag not working

Tags: html5-video, video.js

Having difficulty with video.js (currently at 5.1.9, tested with latest 6.2.0) and the default flag for language tracks. Doesn't appear the default flag is respected - the tracks always default to English (en).

```
<video 
    class="video-js vjs-default-skin"
    controls
    preload="auto" 
    width="640"
    height="360"
    poster="http://localtest.site/poster/SubtitleTest.jpg"
    data-setup='{}' >
    <source src="http://localtest.site/video/SubtitleTest_1200k.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <track kind="captions" src="http://localtest.site//tracks/SubtitleTest_nl.vtt" srclang="nl" label="Dutch" default />
    <track kind="captions" src="http://localtest.site//tracks/SubtitleTest_en.vtt" srclang="en" label="English" />
    <track kind="captions" src="http://localtest.site/tracks/SubtitleTest_es.vtt" srclang="es" label="Spanish" />
</video>
```

It's successfully implemented in the page and the 3 language tracks are switchable, but the the video always begins with the English track. The 'default' flag is never respected.

(Note: After much testing, it does seem to work under video.js v4.9.1; nothing later works with the default flag.)

Am I not initialising something correctly for 5.x?